# How to use thread in asyncio?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I want to new a thread to do a io task with consumer/producer pattern in a asyncio task:

```
import asyncio
import threading
import time
import queue


q = queue.Queue()


def consumer():
    while True:
        v = q.get()
        time.sleep(v)
        print(f"log {v}")


async def work(v):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print(f"work {v}")


async def main():
    t = threading.Thread(target=consumer, daemon=True)
    t.start()
    for i in range(1, 5):
        print(f"start {i}")
        q.put(i)
        loop.create_task(work(i))
        print(f"done {i}")
    t.join()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.run_forever()
```

But the asyncio task cannot be execute because of consumer thread.

Comment: You don't use threads for IO in asyncio. Why [the example](https://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/producer_consumer.html) from the asyncio documentation doesn't work for you?

Comment: @RomanKonoval actually threads in Python are still worth to use with asyncio if you need read/write files in disk or if you have some blocking functions.

Comment: @RomanKonoval just like ArtiomKozyrev say, I want to gzip a big file, but I don't want to block the main event loop.

Comment: You are not doing IO in this case. You are invoking a blocking function that does many things internally (including some IO). The question is misleading. The correct answer to question `how to use thread for doing IO in asyncio?` is `don't do this`. The question `how to use threads for blocking operations in asyncio` is legit.

Comment: gzip it's CPU-bound task, so threads in Python will not help you because of GIL. You need `asyncio.loop.run_in_executor`, combined with `ProcessPoolExecutor`

Comment: @RomanKonoval but io operation like read/write file is just a blocking function in python, I just want to make example simple

Comment: @NobbyNobbs I don't care about gzip time, I just want to  ensure main event loop is not blocked

Comment: Is gzip module release GIL?

Comment: It does not matter how gzip or any library is implemented. in cpython GIL is released every 100 ms for CPU bound workflow or on any IO

Comment: @RomanKonoval it's matters. 100ms it's something like eternity for event loop, if GIL will acquired by gzip thread, event loop and all the coroutines would stuck for 100 ms :shrug:

Comment: @RomanKonoval I am still confused, why cannot I use thread to doing IO if I want to make sure the main event loop not be blocked. Because of GIL?

Comment: @RomanKonoval recently CPU bound ops completely broke my aiohttp app - all operations were blocked and I even did not get majority of error messages from aiohttp - got some errors in 40 minutes despite there was 5 minutes timeout for request. The problem was solved only when I moved heavy CPU bound ops to child processes with the help of multiprocessing module.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of explicitly managing the worker thread and a queue, you can use the thread pool built into asyncio (or create your own if you wish) and call `run_in_executor` to submit tasks to it. For example:

```
import asyncio, time

def blocking_work(v):
    # this function is not async, it will be run in a separate thread
    time.sleep(v)
    print(f"log {v}")

async def work(v):
    # native asyncio work
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    # followed by blocking IO wrapped in thread
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_work, v)
    print(f"work {v}")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*[work(i) for i in range(1, 5)])

asyncio.run(main())
```